# Comprehensive Reading on Graph Coloring

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, coloring

Very frequently, it turns out that I end up learning something entirely new about graph coloring. Is there a good book I could go through for a fairly comprehensive reading on the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following book is a nice summary of classic work in graph coloring:

- Graph Coloring Problems, by Tommy R. Jensen and Bjarne Toft, 1994
  [DOI:10.1002/9781118032497](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118032497).

The following book focues more on coloring algorithms:

- A Guide to Graph Colouring: Algorithms and Applications, by R.M.R. Lewis, 2016 [ISBN:978-3319257280](https://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-25730-3).

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the late response. The first book is great. Haven't had a thorough look at the second but it seems like I would like  a bit more math. Would you happen to know about any of the books written by Ping Zhang?

Comment: Based on the table of contents, the book "Chromatic Graph Theory" by Gary Chartrand and Ping Zhang looks very nice.